# What is the preferred way to do google site verification on ReadTheDocs?

Tags: google-search-console, read-the-docs

The day job has RTD pulling/building our docs from our Gitlab repo, and building automatically.  I'm trying to track down 404 issues and the like with the Google Search Console (we can't help what people link to).

Is there an easy way to either upload the static .html file or the META tag that google asks for, without adding it globally to our documentation tree (since it's ONLY useful to us, on RTD).

I've read the various docs, and RTD's own sites say "use META tags" but they're not clear on how to embed them.

We can't use google analytics (the .js files aren't on RTD).  We can't use the CNAME (we don't control DNS for oursite.readthedocs.io).

Comment: "use META tags" is asking you to override part of the theme template to insert extra `<meta>` tags. If you read more about HTML and Sphinx themes, I think that will become clear to you.

Comment: My second paragraph covers why I felt like putting things into our main doc tree when this meta tag is specific to our RTD mirror *only* feels like the wrong answer.  Is there an RTD-local way to do this?

Comment: Same question on Webmasters Stack Exchange: [How do I add a Google Search Console verification meta tag to a read-the-docs page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/142501/how-do-i-add-a-google-search-console-verification-meta-tag-to-a-read-the-docs-pa)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment variable `READTHEDOCS` to know if you are building on Read the Docs. When building on Read the Docs, you can add those `meta` HTML tag you need.

See the following documentation https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-change-behavior-when-building-with-read-the-docs to know more about how to use this environment variable.